# JavaScript works in IE + Chrome but not FF

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

The following works in IE and Chrom but not FF. Thanks

```
<script>
    Element.setStyle(('table'), {
        'background-image': 'none'
    });
    Element.setStyle(('panel'), {
        'background-image': 'url(/pic.jpg)',
        'background-repeat': 'no-repeat'
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What happens in Firefox? Error messages? Why are your strings enclosed in parentheses?

Comment: @Juhana: The OP's strings are enclosed in parenthesis because he's passing in an object to the `setStyle` function. As for why it's not working, `Element` in FF isn't defined, presumably. Do you get any error messages?

Comment: FF comes up with this error:  `TypeError: Element.setStyle is not a function`.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville Are you talking about the brackets in the second parameters? I'm talking about the first parameters.

Comment: @Juhana: Ah, I see. Well, I honestly have no idea why they're there, but they don't affect the outcome of the script, so that's not the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the setStyle function you're using, but when using JavaScript, Firefox is more particular about hyphens within CSS property names than other browsers.

Where style property names have hyphens, you should be using lower-case camel caplitalization instead - so 'background-image' should be 'backgroundImage' etc. Property values like 'no-repeat' are fine as they are.